# how to check spreadsheet for input errors

Tags: xml, xls

I was generating large XLS (Microsof Ofice Excel spreadsheet) file for a client with XML. The file has 72MB and when I try to open it in LibreOffice it crush on `"General input/output error"` yet when I check the XML with `xmllint myfile.xls` the XML has no input errors.

I'm wondering is there a similar console command that would check the file for errors from a XLS perspective ? (in ubuntu)

I don't have windows and specially I don't have Microsoft office to check it, yet I need to send it to client "perfect" (funny ha ? :) )

The XML looks like the one presented here http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel (bottom one)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is a non-Linux/non-command line trick. Get the free MS Office 365/MS Office Online/OneDrive then check it from the web.

Comment: good point, acceptable, but the thing is that the data is sensitive and my client is nuts about security => no unapproved cloud solutions

Answer (score 0):

Huh, The whole issue seems to be the LibreOffice itself. I've installed `Gnumeric` which is not Java based (it's C based)  and it works well :)

I'm just guessing that it's because LibreOffice is much more heavier (more features per single cell) so I guess Java didn't handle it with memory coverage.

So conclusion: my XLS was ok so all I needed to check was my XML with `xmllint` for any broken XML. If there are no XML issues,then the format seems to be ok for spreadsheet applications.